# Time complexity of modify enum column operation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 22 million rows and 3 columns.

First column is type of String.
Second column is type of Enum.
Third column is type of Timestamp.

Now, I want to make this operation:

```
alter table [table name] modify column [second column name] enum(...)
```

For more details:

Currently, second column with type enum contains 18 elements. I want to add +1 enum element to this second column.

Question is: How I can count the time complexity of this operation?

Comment: Alternatively, abandon the enum, and store allowable values in a separate table

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to change the hole value if ENUM

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY COLUMN Column-name
    ENUM('oldvalue1','oldvalu2e','oldvalue3','newvalue1','newvalw2','newvalue3');
```

Comment: Yeah, I know. But, question is: How I can count the time complexity of this operation?

Comment: i calculate with 300 ms every update, but in sql it is quite simple take  the first 10000 rows add then copy them to a new table, make your changes and then you have an estimate for 10000 rows, after that you multiply the time and this has a another upside, you test your modifications as well.